# How to tile a plane such that moving from one tile to the next in any of the 8 cardinal directions is the same length?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, tiling, spherical-geometry

When tiling the euclidean plane with squares (like most board games), moving diagonally to another tile is longer than moving vertically or horizontally. Is there a tiling such that moving in any of the 8 cardinal directions to another tile is the same length. (not necessarily euclidean). It would also be nice to minimise holonomy.

Comment: what is a direction in a non-Euclidean geometry ?

Comment: This perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagonal_tiling

Comment: @Selim G the same could be said about euclidean geometry. In this case i just mean that the cardinal north always points up no matter the rotation

Comment: In Euclidean geometry, directions are well-defined because since the curvature vanishes, tangent spaces are canonically isometric via the holonomy of Levi-Civitta. This ceases to be true in non-zero curvature. What I mean by that is that it really makes sense to compare directions at any two points in Euclidean geometry, whereas it does not in other geometries.